# color as a function of slider position for setting a color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider, uicolor, cgcolorspace

I am trying to create a color picker tool, that the user could use. The color picker has a slider of all colors and additional slider to set how dark the color is. Both are shown in image 1 and 2:

**Image 1**: picks color:

[image: Image 1]

**Image 2**: sets how dark color is

[image]

I know that I could use a custom image for slider, and than match each color with a position, that would mean that I would need to create huge array and is a lot of work. The second slider that sets how dark color is would still need to be computed at runtime. I'm doubting this approach is any good and therefore ask you if you have a better idea on how to tackle this problem. Perhaps a mathematical function that connects color with slider position, color(x) where x is position of slider, would do the trick. So how to create a color as a function of position and create a slider based on this math function?

Comment: I didn't calculated for color brightness but I suggest you to use `UIColor` method `+ (UIColor *)colorWithHue:(CGFloat)hue saturation:(CGFloat)saturation brightness:(CGFloat)brightness alpha:(CGFloat)alpha;` and change `brightness` as slider moves.

Comment: Is it possible to create a slider based on the value (UIColor* colorWithHue....) method to get visual representation of what the color looks?

Comment: I just want to check what the question is here. You are asking about how to render the slider images so that they are dynamic and can change based on what the user does. You're not asking about how to create a UIColor from a slider are you?

Comment: Basically I am trying to create a slider with static image. The user than moves the slider arrows around and a UIView changes color based on what the color in slider was chosen. The second slider color (the one that only sets the brightness) would change dynamically, based on the color chosen in the first slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have done this before is just by using images.

You could render each pixel based on the position of it etc... but that's very intensive stuff and the image won't actually change.

Various apps already have a hue gradient built in (Pixelmatr and Photoshop both do).

Just create a hue gradient image and use that behind the hue slider.

For the brightness slider create a transparent - black gradient image and place that over the slider. Now you can just set the slider colour and the gradient on top of it will make it look correct.

I used this technique to create this colour picker in an app of mine...

[image]

The "slider" on the left uses a single image with a hue gradient.

The "brightness / saturation" picker on the right uses a single image with a white-transparent gradient from left to right and a black-transparent gradient from bottom to top. Then I just have to set the background colour based on the hue.

**Example**

All colours in iOS use 0.0-1.0 based colours.

So all you need is a percentage of how far along each view you are.

So you have a position as a `CGPoint` and need to produce a percentage.

Each colour is "3 dimensional" (4 with alpha but I didn't include it) so you need three percentages.

For the hue view that is easy...

```
// put this inside the hue view (if you're not using a UISlider
// this works vertically you ay need yours to work horizontally.
- (CGFloat)hueValueForTouchPosition:(CGPoint)touchPoint {
    return touchPoint.y / CGRectGetHeight(self.frame);
}
```

This will return the correct hue value based on the position of the touch within the view.

Now you can use that to set the background color of the brightness view.

```
// this will change the background color of the brightness view to match the selected hue
CGFloat hue = [self.hueView hueValueForTouchPosition:touchPoint];
self.brightnessView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue brightness:1.0 saturation:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Now you just have to do the same with the brightness

Comment: that approach seam the best. How do I render pixel color based on the position of the pixel? it would be greate if there were a method that accepts a pixel and outputs the color of that pixel..

Comment: You can create that method very easily. But don't try to be pixel perfect. Let me put an example.

Comment: Ok. You also mentioned using gradient image as a slider. That is indeed what I want but I don't know how to make a connection between slider position and color chosen.

Comment: @krompir2 what is your slider? is it a `UISlider`?

Comment: yes, the plan was to use UISlider. Although there is nothing forbidding me to use something else.

Comment: @krompir2 well if you use a `UISlider` then just use the `value` of the slider. I preferred to use a `UIView` as I could customise it more. The update to my question shows how to use a `UIView`.

Comment: Just wrote a test program to see it how it works. It works beautifully. Thank you! I couldn't have done it without you.

Comment: @krompir2 nice one! Glad you got it to work. Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

1. Get `UITouch` event methods by implementing in a subclass of slider view.
2. Get `position(CGPoint)` of touch points.
3. Do calculation like below

   At max brightness will be `1.0` reduce it using following

   ```
   CGFloat currentBrightness = 1.0 - ((position.x - slider.frame.origin.x)/slider.frame.size.width);

   UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:currentHue
                             saturation:currentSaturation
                             brightness:currentBrightness
                                  alpha:1.0];
   ```

Where `currentHue` and `currentSaturation` will be calculated from color selection slider.

Comment: I believe the question is about rendering the sliders rather than using the sliders to create the colour.

Answer (score 1):

You need a no less than three sliders, They can be RGB or HSB sliders. then you can directly generate the current color from these methods :

*For RGB*

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:slider1.value
                Green:slider2.value
                 Blue:slider3.value
                alpha:1.0];
```

*For HSB*

```
[UIColor colorWithHue:slider1.value
           saturation:slider2.value
           brightness:slider3.value
                alpha:1.0];
```

As for dynamically setting the background gradient of the sliders, the gradient for each slider can be obtained by varying its value keeping the other two constant.

for example, if *`H:0.2 S:0.6 B:0.5`* is the current slider position, then the gradients would be -

*Slider1* : *H:**0.0** S:0.6 B:0.5* to *H:**1.0** S:0.6 B:0.5*
*Slider2* : *H:0.2 S:**0.0** B:0.5* to *H:0.2 S:**1.0** B:0.5*
*Slider3* : *H:0.2 S:0.6 B:**0.0*** to *H:0.2 S:0.6 B:**1.0***

**OR**

if you want to go the easy way, there are tons of libraries out there. See [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=color+picker) for e.g

Comment: I believe the question is how to render the sliders rather than how to use sliders to create the colour.